# C++ reference calls 'wrong' destructor

Tags: c++

Why does below snippet print:

```
Constructing Working on this
Constructing working on that
Destructing working on that
Destructing working on that
```

I would expect "constructing this + that" and "destructing this that".

So the idea here is to have to have a reference to a `workingItem` and then do something in the destructor if something goes out of scope. It seems that this does not work, and my question is why? Does this cause a memory leak? Also why don't I get "destructing this" because I did not overwrite `a`?

I can get this working by making `workingItem` a pointer, but my question is: is there also a way to get this working by using a ref?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A {
 private:
   std::string str;
 public:
   A(const std::string& s) : str(s) { std::cout << "Constructing "<<s<<std::endl; };
   ~A() { std::cout << "Destructing "<<str<<std::endl; };
};

int main() {
    A a("Working on this");
    A& workingItem=a;
    A a2("working on that");
    workingItem=a2;
}
```

Comment: You did overwrite `a`, in this line: `workingItem=a2;`. You cannot reassign a reference, `operator=` will always be applied to the object it refers to.

Comment: If you don't think you overwrote `a`, what did you think you did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement a `operator=` to get the full picture:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
 private:
   std::string str;
 public:
   A(const std::string& s) : str(s) { std::cout << "Constructing "<<s<<std::endl; };
   ~A() { std::cout << "Destructing "<<str<<std::endl; };
   A& operator=(const A& other){
       std::cout << "assign " << other.str << " to " << str <<"\n";
       str = other.str;
       return *this;
   }
}; 

int main() {
    A a("Working on this");
    A& workingItem=a;
    A a2("working on that");
    workingItem=a2;
}
```

Output is:

```
Constructing Working on this
Constructing working on that
assign working on that to Working on this
Destructing working on that
Destructing working on that
```

You cannot rebind references. This line `A& workingItem=a;` initializes the reference `workingItem` to refer to `a`.

This line is something completely different: `workingItem=a2;` it assigns `a2` to the object refered to by `workingItem`, and that is `a1`. It is the same as `a1 = a2;`. Hence you end up with two identical `A`s that get destroyed when `main` returns.

In general it is important to be aware of the difference between initialization, `T x = y;`, and assignment, `x = y;`.